# Manually constructing node tree: how do I rename <ObjectNode> tags

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I'm trying to set up code to create a node tree using jackson which can then be used to write either JSON or XML. I've created the node tree manually like so:

```
XmlMapper NodeMap = new XmlMapper();

ObjectNode rootNode = NodeMap.createObjectNode();
ObjectNode currentNode = rootNode.putObject("Examples");
currentNode
    .put("Puppy", TRUE)
    .put("Apple", 2)
    .put("Jet", "Li");
currentNode = rootNode.putObject("Single");
currentNode.put("One", 1);

String writePath = "C:/users/itsameamario/Documents/basicXMLtest.xml";
NodeMap.writeValue(new File(writePath), rootNode);
```

My output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ObjectNode>
    <Examples>
        <Puppy>true</Puppy>
        <Apple>2</Apple>
        <Jet>Li</Jet>
    </Examples>
    <Single>
        <One>1</One>
    </Single>
</ObjectNode>
```

However I would like to have control over "ObjectNode" and rename it to something more appropriate.

When manually constructing the node tree as I do above, *how would I rename it to something I can control*?

Comment: "ideal output" is not a valid `XML`. Check it with online [validator](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator). You need to have root node which wraps `Examples` and `Single`.

Comment: Question adjusted to just be about renaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rename the rootNode you need to use an ObjectWriter. Try this:

```
XmlMapper NodeMap = new XmlMapper();
final ObjectWriter writer = NodeMap.writer().withRootName("Pumpernickel"); //Rename as appropriate

ObjectNode rootNode = NodeMap.createObjectNode();
ObjectNode currentNode = rootNode.putObject("Examples");
currentNode
    .put("Puppy", true)
    .put("Apple", 2)
    .put("Jet", "Li");
currentNode = rootNode.putObject("Single");
currentNode.put("One", 1);

String writePath = "C:/users/itsameamario/Documents/basicXMLtest.xml";
writer.writeValue(new File(writePath), rootNode); // Make sure you replace this line too.
```

Your "ObjectNode"s should be replaced with "Pumpernickel"s. Rename as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Alexander's answer worked for me. This is surprisingly the only article I found on the Internet related to this  tag. I've written up a blog post with some additional findings: https://christopherkao.me/constructing-an-xml-payload-in-java-for-an-api-call/.